# Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread, but I didn't delete from wrong thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

My python program allows users to make a maze by drag and drop interference. It even searches for the correct path in the maze. However 720 variables need to be defined and binded for the grid where the maze will be built, for this purpose I used a loop which takes some time to work, henceforth I made a loading screen. When the program loads fully, the loading screen closes and it's thread dies but when I close the main window, I get the error(not when the loading screen closes but when I close the main window) `Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread`. Here's a simplified version of my code to show what I'm trying to do:

```
from tkinter import *
from threading import Thread

loaded = False

def load():

    load = Tk()

    Label(load, text = "Loading...").pack()

    def check():

        if loaded:

            load.destroy()

        else:

            load.after(1, check)

    load.mainloop()


t = Thread(target = load)
t.start()

root = Tk()

#defining the 720 variables
for x in range(0, 720):
    print(x)
    exec("var" + str(x) + " = " + str(x))  

loaded = True

root.mainloop()
```

I did read a few other questions on stack overflow, and I found out this happens when you delete the window from another thread(not the main thread), however I am deleting the loading screen from the thread in which it is running itself, not main thread. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

This error specifically is caused by there being multiple instances of `Tk` in one app. There should *always* be only one instance of `Tk` in a `tkinter` app. If you want to create secondary windows, use `Toplevel` for them instead of `Tk`.

But you'll notice that if you do replace `load = Tk` with `load = Toplevel`, `load` doesn't show at all. When using threads in `tkinter` applications, it's a good idea to keep all of the `tkinter` stuff in one thread. If you split any `tkinter` widgets or operations into separate threads, it can cause problems. You should put the `for` loop inside `load()`, and put everything that's currently inside `load()` where the `for` loop was. This prevents any `tkinter` function calls or widget creation from happening in two different threads.

Third, I strongly recommend that you don't define variables in a loop like that. It makes it troublesome when trying to access the variables after creating them, and it's slow. For so many numbers, you can create a list and just append the numbers to the list. In my example, the list is called `numbers`.

Fourth, you will need to use `global` in your `load` function, so that the `loading` variable can be used properly in the thread. You also have two variables named `load`: the function and the window. You should rename one of them so that one doesn't overshadow the other. In my example, I rename `load` the window to `load_window`.

To make the `Toplevel` show on top, you can set `load_window.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)`.

Here is what the code should look like:

```py
from tkinter import *
# import time # Uncomment this to show the loading window for a little longer
from threading import Thread

loaded = False
numbers = []

def load():
    global loaded, numbers
    # Add the numbers to the list
    numbers = [x for x in range(0, 720)]
    # time.sleep(1) # Uncomment this to show the loading window for a little bit longer
    loaded = True

root = Tk()
load_window = Toplevel(root)
Label(load_window, text = "Loading...").pack()

t = Thread(target = load)
t.start()

def check():
    global loaded, load_window
    if loaded:
        load_window.destroy()
    else:
        load_window.after(1, check)

check()
load_window.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
load_window.mainloop()
root.mainloop()
```

Note that when you run the code, you get a `_tkinter.TclError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/test.py", line 29, in <module>
    load_window.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1976, in wm_attributes
    return self.tk.call(args)
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!toplevel"
```

This is because `load()` runs so fast that it destroys `loaded_window` before `-topmost` is set. As you probably know, calling functions on a destroyed widget raises errors. So this whole loading window would only really be needed with higher numbers. Even when I use `range(0, 900000)` instead of `range(0, 720)`, the code runs, but it's still so fast that you only see `load_window` for a split second.

If you still want to see the loading window, you can uncomment the `import time` and `time.sleep(...` lines, and it will cause `load_window` to wait a second before closing.

Comment: But I am not adding numbers to a list, I am defining 720 variables(Buttons)

Comment: @Devyansh Is there a specific reason you need to define 720 variables, instead of using a list? Will a list not work for you? You can still append `Button`s to a list.

Comment: I have tried using arrays, I have tryed ```dict``` and ```list``` but none worked

Comment: @Devyansh In order to help, I'll I need more information about _what_ doesn't work. Do you get errors with the code in this answer, or when you try to make a list of the buttons? Or something else?

Comment: I am making a grid with many Labels(tkinter Labels), each label has bindings for <Enter> and <Leave> bindings, for this reason I have to define 720 variables using ```exec``` function in a ```for``` loop

Comment: @Devyansh In that case, a list should work. It'll work in much the same way as using 720 variables, except that instead of using each `varX` variable number, you would use a list index `labels_list[X]`. For example, instead of `var3`, you would use `labels_list[3]`. It really doesn't change that much of the functionality of the code, except to make it faster and more dependable.

Comment: that exactly is the problem, that did not work, I tried a lot and it did not work, so I decided using exec

Comment: @Devyansh You still haven't explained _what_ doesn't work. Using a list, when done correctly, _will_ work. If you want, maybe I can show you in my answer. But unless you can let me know what doesn't work, I'll just have to delete my unsatisfactory answer and move on. I can't help unless I have enough information about the problem I'm trying to help with. If it's too complicated to explain in the comments, maybe you could ask another question about it.

Comment: ok sorry for not giving info, I'll give a brief but exact description: I am using a for loop with a range in it, the code is ```for x in range(0, 720)```. Now inside this loop I execute ```exec("cell" + str(x) + " = Label(grid_frame)```. I hope this shows what I am saying clearly

Comment: @Devyansh Sorry, I didn't word that correctly; I meant what is the problem with the code you have. Like, what are its errors messages/other problems?

Comment: actually there's no error message, It's just I am defining and binding cells using for loop so when the cell is binded with a lambda. It's like it has to change background colour of the cell but it always changes the background colour of last cell but now tht stuff is not an issue so let's leave it, we hv been discussing on this for over a week and tht is not the problem(pls don't take this in a bad way, I'm not being rude)

Comment: @Devyansh I understand. Do you want me to delete my answer, or leave it here?

Comment: no pls don't take it in tht way i just wanted to ask why this error occurs, u cn leave ur answer here, u need not delete it